# Magento 2.2.5 Not Sending New Order Email To Guest

Tags: magento2.2, magento-2.2.5, order-email, guest-checkout

I've got a live 2.2.5 single store site and whenever a Guest customer places an order, the New Order Email fails to send. It works for registered users perfectly.

Instead of sending the New Order Email, the site sends an Order Update email, saying "Your order has been updated to processing etc." even though Order Update emails are disabled.

I've tried everything and regardless of what payment method is used the New Order template will not send.

Even when I click the "Send Email" link in the order view in the admin, it resends the Order Update email it sent in the first place, not the New Order Email.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies everyone

Totally my fault, I had the wrong template set at store view level and was checking it at website level.

It's working now.